# Убрать запятую перед 'and'

Tags: python, строки, list

К списку нужно добавить запятую после каждого элемента кроме последнего, перед ним нужно добавить 'and' что я сделал, но не могу додумать как убрать запятую перед 'and' чтобы было орфографически правильно оформлен вывод.

Мой вывод: 2 eggs, 1 liter sugar, 1 tsp salt, and vinegar

Должно быть: 2 eggs, 1 liter sugar, 1 tsp salt and vinegar

```
    def format_ingredients(items):
        items[-1] = 'and ' + items[-1]
        return ', '.join(items[:])


    list = ["2 eggs", "1 liter sugar", "1 tsp salt", "vinegar"]
    print(format_ingredients(list))
```

Comment: Наверное, проще всего заменить последнюю запятую (rfind или по длине последнего слова из списка) на " and"

Comment: Я нашел последнюю запятую при помощи rfind(','), но подскажи как её заменить.
Очень хороший метод, интересно для себя.

Comment: `s = s[:r] + ' and' + s[r:]`, однако способ из ответа проще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, не называйте переменные зарезервированными именами `(built-in)` в `Python`, таким образом вы переопределяете стандартные объекты и это может вызвать необычное поведение. [Список всех зарезервированных имён](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

По поводу вашей проблемы, можно решить "в лоб", как и написано у вас в условии, все элементы кроме последнего соединить запятой, а перед последним отдельно добавить "and":

```
list_ = ["2 eggs", "1 liter sugar", "1 tsp salt", "vinegar"]

print(', '.join(list_[:-1]) + ' and ' + list_[-1])
```

Вывод:

```
2 eggs, 1 liter sugar, 1 tsp salt and vinegar
```